# Typescript object keys from generic parameters

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to create a function that accepts an array of objects and then one or more parameters that specify the properties which will be used on that array.

For example, either of these:

```
update([{ name: 'X', percentage: 1, value: 2 }], 'percentage', 'value');
update([{ name: 'X', foo: 1, bar: 2 }], 'foo', 'bar');
```

### Attempt 1:

```
function update<T extends { name: string }, A extends keyof T, B extends keyof T>(data: T[], a: A, b: B) {
    for (const row of data) {
        console.log(row.name, row[a] * row[b]);
        row[a] = row[a] * row[b];
    }
}
```

- When I try to use `row[a]` as a number I get an error because the type is `T[A]` and seemingly it doesn't know that's a number
- When I try to assign a number to `row[a]` I get `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[A]'.(2322)`

### Attempt 2:

```
type Entry<A extends string, B extends string> = { name: string } & Record<A | B, number>;

function update<T extends Entry<A, B>, A extends string, B extends string>(data: T[], a: A, b: B) {
    for (const row of data) {
        console.log(row.name, row[a] * row[b]);
        row[a] = row[a] * row[b];
    }
}
```

- This fixes the issue when using `row[a]`, it seems to be ok with me using it as a number
- But I still get `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[A]'.(2322)` when trying to assign a number to `row[a]` (or anything for that matter)

  - Suprisingly, even removing the `{ name: string }` from `Entry` doesn't fix this, typescript still won't allow me to assign anything here for some reason

This seems like a fairly common thing to what to do in JS, but I have no idea how to make Typescript understand it.

Comment: I've noticed that TS doesn't like letting you write to a generic `A` property of something of the form `Record<A, Foo> & Bar`, but it's fine with just `Record<A, Foo>`.  So my suggestion would be to do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2PKxm).  Does that work for you or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz I was hoping there was a way to do this without casts but if not that's certainly a useful option that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “cast” here?  That’s a somewhat ambiguous term and TS doesn’t have anything called “casting” per se.  There are type assertions (this is what people normally mean by “cast” but I didn’t use any in my example) and type annotations (this is what I used and I suppose you could call this an “upcast”).

Comment: By cast I mean any use of `as`, because it means you're having to force something because typescript doesn't have enough information - I always try to give typescript that information, if possible.

Comment: But I’m not using `as`, so I’m not sure what you were referring to in your prior comment.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Oh sorry I see what you mean now! I think `const r: Record<A, number> = row;` actually narrows the type (your comment says widen). I think this is my preferred solution since it doesn't use `as`.

Comment: No, it widens the type.  Widening is the same as upcasting and is generally safe; narrowing is the same as downcasting and is often unsafe (unless you do some sort of check first).  Every `{name: string} & Record<A | B, number>` is also a `Record<A, number>` but not vice versa, so the latter type is *wider* than the former.  Anyway I'm happy to write up an answer explaining my approach, terminology notwithstanding.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. If you make an answer I will upvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need something like your `Entry<A, B>` definition to represent something which is known to have a `number` property at the `A` and `B` keys.  Just saying that `A` and `B` are `keyof typeof data` isn't enough, because for all the compiler knows, there might be non-numeric properties at `keyof typeof data` (indeed, the `name` property is non-numeric).

Furthermore you don't want to have `data` be of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T extends Entry<A, B>`.  That [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) is an upper bound, so `T` could be something very specific like `{name: string, pi: 3.14, e: 2.72}` with properties of `number` [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  The only value assignable to the type `3.14` is `3.14`, so the compiler correctly prevents you from assigning `row[a] * row[b]` to `row[a]`.  So we just want `data` to be of type `Entry<A, B>` and not some unknown subtype of `Entry<A, B>`.  That gives us this:

```
function update<A extends string, B extends string>(data: Entry<A, B>[], a: A, b: B) {
  for (const row of data) {
    console.log(row.name, row[a] * row[b]);  
    row[a] = row[a] * row[b]; // error!  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Entry<A, B>[A]'
  }
}
```

which *still breaks* on the assignment.  The compiler is unable to see that `number` is assignable to `Entry<A, B>[A]`. Something about the intersection is confusing it. I think this is a limitation of TypeScript (although someone could try to argue that if `A` is `"name"` then `Entry<A, B>[A]` is of type `number & string`, also known as `never`, and thus the compiler is correct to warn you that `number` is not necessarily assignable to `Entry<A, B>[A]`, but this is pretty pedantic and not particularly useful in most situations, in my opinion).  I haven't found a particular issue in GitHub talking about it.

On the other hand, the compiler *can* see that `number` is assignable to `Record<A, number>[A]`.  Since `Entry<A, B>` is a subtype of `Record<A, number>`, we can then widen `row` to `Record<A, number>` safely (modulo the above `"name"` pedantry above) by assigning it to a new variable with an appropriate [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables):

```
function update<A extends string, B extends string>(data: Entry<A, B>[], a: A, b: B) {
  for (const row of data) {
    console.log(row.name, row[a] * row[b]);
    const r: Record<A, number> = row; // okay
    r[a] = row[a] * row[b];
  }
}
```

And now everything works as desired:

```
update([{ name: 'X', percentage: 1, value: 2 }], 'percentage', 'value');
update([{ name: 'X', foo: 1, bar: 2 }], 'foo', 'bar');
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ts=4.7.2#code/K4BwJghgLgpgFAbQN4AIB2EC2MBcKDkAGvgDQogwBOAxjGlBAOa4oCMZAbhADbAsBMKAL4BdMvgo06DZqQJdeMfAEoA3AChQkWIlQZseInIBmAe1N52KAEYRKeQaPFnTc-LcoqN6qAE8KKACi9JS+ADwAgigwAB6waGAAziiJUJQAlmiMZABC0XF0SSlpmYwAfCgAvCh6WCypGVnCKABkKABKMNSmlGCRKAA+KDlkaMCY1lRl3sbAaNRQ6aZoKFrQMADypiCJ-bHxRQ2lufkHyUdZZXDaEHjBaeERuWUIYii3KE82eDnKNeooFBmSgoODdNCpFCUUwAdxQpmMKBufyQAMBKHBiVM3BgADpuKZGHBoTDcfoYGQSQgICIUAAqKGwhDWERqQFowFUmlVRkw6m0hlUlmqFAAelF0Uo0MoAEJAQAVfwwAhjCZUfAodLJNCmKDvRKJdKMDDWHEoKCmc1Kgj3UKRZ4ICIifBooTqN3qWbzRbLVbgdZ7AoJc4lLInfaFEONcrXaAfW2PB1vD5faw-FFo4GgzF6knwxHI-7ojHLLE4-GE4mwsl1SlM7mCpkstQcksQ3N4TrdXr29DjSaUCrVEki8UoAAWEA4yotKBh6TAdF55stXZ6fS+qoHZTIc2BUDm624vlblH5PK5At5zJEGkBbqEQA)

Answer (score 1):

You can create Mapped type (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to address number values, and then add `{name: string}`. Unfortunately you have to cast multiplication result to `T[keyof T]` as TS cannot figure out that only number can be assigned to non `name` fields.

```js
update([{ name: 'X', percentage: 1, value: 2 }], 'percentage', 'value');
update([{ name: 'X', foo: 1, bar: 2 }], 'foo', 'bar');

type NumberValues<Type> = {
  [Property in keyof Omit<Type, 'name'>]: number;
};

function update<T extends NumberValues<T> & {name: string}>(data: T[], a: keyof T, b: keyof T) {
    for (const row of data) {
      const aValue = row[a];
        console.log(row.name, row[a] * row[b]);
        row[a] = row[a] * row[b] as T[keyof T];
    }
}
```

From there you can modify `update` method to accept multiple params of `keyof T` type like below:

```js
function update<T extends NumberValues<T> & {name: string}>(data: T[], ...args: (keyof T)[]) {
    for (const row of data) {
        console.log(row.name, row[args[0]] * row[args[1]]);
        row[args[0]] = row[args[0]] * row[args[1]] as T[keyof T];
    }
}
```

If you want to avoid casting, you can save extracted row to variable which you can type, similarly to @jcalz solution:

```
function update<T extends NumberValues<T> & {name: string}>(data: T[], ...args: (keyof T)[]) {
    for (const row of data) {
        const r: {[property in keyof T]: number} = row;
        r[a] = row[a] * row[b];
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you were aiming for that, but proposed solution allows you to add multiple fields to object, and pass *not all* keys, so for example:

```js
update([{ name: 'X', percentage: 1, value: 2, anotherVal: 5 }], 'percentage', 'value');
```

will work as well.

Comment: Oh! I was trying to do something like the Omit but I was trying to use Exclude and I couldn't figure out how to make it work with keyof. Shame we still have to cast though.

Comment: You can use same trick as @jcalz proposed, and extract row to separate variable which will be typed accordingly: `const r: {[property in keyof T]: number} = row; r[a] = row[a] * row[b];`.